# Google sheets show open or closed at the moment

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-timestamp

There is a client’s working time, it is necessary to display the client is currently open or closed. Is it possible?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome. It's not clear what you are asking for. Are you looking for a formula? What you have tried so far? Have you done any search/research effort as is suggested in [ask]?

Comment: Hello! I am looking for =arrayformula formula if it is possible.

Comment: The current answer already includes an arrayformula. If you need further help add some sample input/output data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple formula put in cell C1

```
=arrayformula({"isOpen?";if(A2:A="","",if((timevalue(now())>=A2:A)*(timevalue(now())<=B2:B),"Open","Closed"))})
```

as an added bonus this will tell you how many hours to open or close in D1

```
=arrayformula({"Status?";if(A2:A="","",if(C2:C="Closed","Opens in "&text(24*((A2:A<timevalue(now()))+A2:A-timevalue(now())),"#.#")&" hours","Closes in "&text(24*((B2:B<timevalue(now()))+B2:B-timevalue(now())),"#.#")&" hours"))})
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the formulas, but there is one problem. When I use this, the formula begins to add an infinite number of lines. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I figured it out, I should put the formula in A1 to make it work. Thank you very much!

Comment: The formula is not always correct, for example, if the client’s opening time is 18:00 and the closing time is 2:00 and now is working time, then it will show that it is closed.

Comment: I wonder what script is used in google maps to show open place or closed :-)

Comment: @VladimirMelnikov if you put opens in column A and closes in column B the formula works fine.